# Compensating Saturation Voltage of a transistor

Tags: transistors, compensation

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fYCZOu.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I am working on this circuit, which is a voltage controlled oscillator. I am using the transistor as a switch in this circuit. The problem is that it is not an ideal switch. It has a saturation voltage, say, 0.4-0.6V. I have to compensate for this effect by may be.. using a matched transistor or anything. But, I haven't been able to get any idea. Could someone give a hint as to how to proceed?

Thanks!

EDIT-[image]

I did it this way finally. The duty cycle was 50% .

Comment: If you reduce R3 greatly and Increase R1R1 then the BJT will saturate better meaning much lower Vce sat.

Comment: @Autistic How will Vce sat decrease? It will be constant for a transistor except with changes in temperature right?  Anyway, I don't want to just reduce it. I want to remove it completely.. and I think it is possible using a matched transistor. (I dont want the circuit to be temperature dependent.)

Comment: Vce will decrease when base current is a significant % of collector current .If you want to do better then a little cheap mosfet like 2N7000 would work well .

Comment: @Austic is correct - look at any full datasheet for the transistor- you will see Vce(sat) can be as low as 10mV or so under the right conditions.

Comment: @Autistic I understand that part. Thank you. I am though looking for compensating completely if possible.

Comment: @Autistic Please check my edit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Increase the resistors R1, R2 by at least an order of magnitude and decrease the capacitor proportionally - try maybe a few hundred pF.

Also decrease the value of R3 to maybe 1-2K, and you should be able to get Vce(sat) down to tens of mV.

You can also replace the transistor with a small MOSFET and the then you'll have zero offset and just Rds(on), which can be very low (even a 2N7000 will have only a few ohms resistance, and you can get parts with much lower on resistance).

Comment: Thank you, but what I want is a complete removal of Vce(sat) since I don't want the circuit to be temperature dependent. I just want to know if it's possible to make it completely ideal. Someone said that it's possible using matched transistors with same Vsat. I looked for a way to do that.

Comment: Use a MOSFET. Years ago we had other solutions but this is the best one today. And increase those resistors R1/R2, the op-amp won't work well with such high current demand.

Comment: Increase R1 and R2. Using a MOSFET makes the problem go away. Far easier than compensating imperfectly with matched transistors. Bear in mind that the time delay of the amplifiers will cause a non-linearity in the control of the VCO comparable to the offset effect you're trying to reduce!

Comment: @SpehroPefhany Please check my edit